# Rails with mysql "Unknown type 'json' for column 'special_info'"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

I have created Rails(3.2) application with mysql(5.7.16) database. I have used json column in some tables and it's working fine. But I can see some commented code like following in my schema.rb file

```
# Could not dump table "shopping_cart_precheckout_details" because of following StandardError
# Unknown type 'json' for column 'special_info'
```

Migration

```
class CreateShoppingCartItemSpecialInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shopping_cart_item_special_infos do |t|
      t.integer :shopping_cart_checkout_option_id
      t.column :special_info, :json

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is this affect the production environment and why this commented code added in schema.rb file ?

Comment: @e4c6 : What do you mean? I can't understand what you come to say ,Please read the question clearly

Comment: can you post migration code for column `special_info` ?

Comment: @sajan: I have added migration code

Comment: this looks fine but I am not sure about json support for mysql in rails 3. I have used with postgres only. maybe you can try changing schema format by putting `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in applictaion.rb and use the current migration.

Answer (score 5):

Native support for native JSON column types in Mysql is only available from Rails 5 onwards: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21110

For Rails 4, `json_on_rails` may be considered: https://github.com/saveriomiroddi/json_on_rails

Comment: That fixed the issue ! Thank you @prusswan 